# Vue <router-link> not working when swipe back on iOS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have an App.vue page that contains 2 columns. The first column is a list of users, the second column is a list of messages. When I click on a user in column 1, the message list will be loaded corresponding to that user. I show/hide column 1 and column 2 according to the following condition

```js
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4 idcvs" v-show="!this.mobileMode || typeof $route.params.id == 'undefined'">
        <ListConversation />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-12 col-lg-8 idchat" v-show="!this.mobileMode || $route.params.id > 0">
        <router-view :key="$route.path" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is on Mobile interface iOS. When I use the back button of the browser (safari, chrome) everything works properly but when I swipe back, on my first click on an user in the list, nothing happens. All activity return only in 2nd click.

*(Translated by Google)*

[image: Screen record]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would asume your id doesn't get set right. Can  you share the code of what happens when you swipe left?

I also think it's not necessary to use 'typeof'.

v-show="!this.mobileMode || !$route.params.id" should work as well